AWS Lambda http.request get always timeout also if works properly
we have a strange situation, we created an AWS Lambda that make an HTTP POST (with JSON body) using http.request, below the code:
export const handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
  const bodyj = JSON.stringify(event, null, 2);
    const req =  https.request(options, (res) => {
        let body = '';
        console.log('Status:', res.statusCode);
        console.log('Headers:', JSON.stringify(res.headers));
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        console.log('Successfully processed HTTPS response');
    });

    req.encoding = 'utf8';
    req.write(bodyj);

    req.end();
    console.log('Successfully processed END HTTPS response');
  
};

The POST request works fine, but any times the Lambda terminate with status: Failed with reason "Task timed out after 30.03 seconds".
We are sure that the http.request works fine because:

we received the body JSON sent with POST on beckend side
in logs of Lambda we are able to see the logs printed in the functions "Status: 200"

Maybe we are missing somethings in function that istruct http.request that all is termineted when receve the HTTP 200 OK?
Many thanks!
We expect that if the http.request receive an HTTP 200 OK the function terminate with Status=success

You forgot to send a done signal, let's call callback(); right after console.log('Successfully processed HTTPS response'); line

Hi hoangdv, thanks for replay, with 'callback();' the problem still exists, I fixed using 'context.succeed();' ;-)
